# WordPress - only show (custom) posts that are tagged featured

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I'm currently building a site which is based on the templatic events v2 theme. I have done some customization which is working fine, but this one is kind of out of my reach.

The problem is as following.

I need to build a widget which only outputs the events (custom posts) that are tagged as featured. Right now I have got some different ways of showing events, but they are pretty much just sorted by category or by date.

example site: http://www.blaest.no/jonnysnorkel

Here is a the current code for my widget the widget I'm working on:

```
    class blaestfeatured extends WP_Widget {
    function blaestfeatured() {
    //Constructor
        $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'widget category List View', 'description' => 'Custom Featured event widget by Christoffer Sandstrøm' );
        $this->WP_Widget('blaestfeatured', 'blaestfeatured', $widget_ops);
    }

    function widget($args, $instance) {
    // prints the widget

        extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);
        echo $before_widget;
        $widget_id= $args['widget_id'];
        $title = empty($instance['title']) ? '' : apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
        $category = empty($instance['category']) ? '' : apply_filters('widget_category', $instance['category']);
        $post_number = empty($instance['post_number']) ? '5' : apply_filters('widget_post_number', $instance['post_number']);
        $post_link = empty($instance['post_link']) ? '' : apply_filters('widget_post_link', $instance['post_link']);
        $more_link = empty($instance['more_link']) ? '' : apply_filters('widget_more_link', $instance['more_link']);
        $character_cout = empty($instance['character_cout']) ? '15' : apply_filters('widget_character_cout', $instance['character_cout']);
        $sorting = empty($instance['event_sorting']) ? 'Latest Published' : apply_filters('widget_event_sorting', $instance['event_sorting']);
         ?>
          <h3 class=""><?php echo $title; ?> </h3>
          <ul>
          <?php //$type = get_option('ptthemes_event_sorting');
            if ( $sorting != '' )
            {
                global $wpdb;
                if ( $sorting == 'Random' )
                {
                    $orderby = "(select $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value from $wpdb->postmeta where $wpdb->postmeta.post_id = p.ID and $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key like \"st_date\") ASC, rand()";
                }
                elseif ( $sorting == 'Alphabetical' )
                {
                    $orderby = "p.post_title ASC";
                }elseif($sorting =='s_date'){
                    $today = date('Y-m-d');
                     $orderby = "(select $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value from $wpdb->postmeta where $wpdb->postmeta.post_id = p.ID and $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key like \"st_date\") ASC";
                }
                else
                {
                    $orderby = "(select $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value from $wpdb->postmeta where $wpdb->postmeta.post_id=p.ID and $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'featured_h') ASC, p.post_date DESC";
                }
            }
            ?>
          <?php 
            global $post,$wpdb;
            if($category)
            {
                $category = "'".str_replace(",","','",$category)."'";
                $sqlsql = " and p.ID in (select tr.object_id from $wpdb->term_relationships tr join $wpdb->term_taxonomy t on t.term_taxonomy_id=tr.term_taxonomy_id where t.term_id in ($category)  )";
            }
            
            $today = date('Y-m-d');
            if ( false === ( $latest_menus = get_transient( 'onecolumnslist'.$widget_id ) ) ) {
                // It wasn't there, so regenerate the data and save the transient       
                $where = "AND p.ID in (select $wpdb->postmeta.post_id from $wpdb->postmeta where $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key='end_date' and date_format($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value,'%Y-%m-%d')>='".$today."') ";
                @$sql = "select p.* from $wpdb->posts p where p.post_type='".CUSTOM_POST_TYPE1."' and (p.post_status='publish' or p.post_status='recurring' ) AND (p.ID in ( select $wpdb->postmeta.post_id from $wpdb->postmeta where $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key='event_type' and $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value ='Regular event')) $sqlsql $where order by $orderby limit $post_number";
                $latest_menus = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
                set_transient( 'onecolumnslist'.$widget_id, $latest_menus, 60*60*12 );
            }
            
            $pcount=0;
            if($latest_menus)
            {
                foreach($latest_menus as $post) :
                setup_postdata($post);
                $pcount++; ?>
                    <?php 
                    $is_parent = $post->post_parent;
                    if($is_parent)
                        $post_id = $post->post_parent;
                    else
                        $post_id = $post->ID;
                    $post_images = bdw_get_images_with_info($post_id,'thumb');
                    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ) , 'single-post-thumbnail'  );
                    if($image[0] != '')
                        $thumb = $image[0];
                    elseif($post_images[0]['file'] != '')
                        $thumb = $post_images[0]['file']; ?>
                            
                        <?php
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'eventcategory' ); // Definerer måten å hente cssclassen for terms.
                        
if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : 

    $classcategory = array();

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $classcategory[] = $term->name;
    }
                        
    $postclasscategory = join( ", ", $classcategory );
?>   

                

<?php
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'event',
   'meta_query' => array(
       array(
           'key' => 'featured_h',
           'value' => 'h',
       )
   )
 );
 $query = new WP_Query($args);
 while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
     <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php get_post_class(); ?> ><?php } ?>
           <h3 class="<?php echo $postclasscategory; ?>" > <?php echo get_formated_date(get_post_meta($post->ID,'st_date',true));?> </h3>
           <div class="eventcontainer">
            <?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID,'featured_h',true) == 'h' ) { ?><div class="featured_img_s"></div><?php }?>
            <?php if ( $thumb != '' ) { ?>
            <a class="headliner-img" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" width="290" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"  /></a>
            <?php
            } else { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID) ; ?>" class="headliner-img"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()."/images/no-image.png"; ?>" height="120" alt="<?php echo @$post_img[0]['alt']; ?>" /></a>
            </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>

                

                    <h3 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3> 
                
                 </li> <!-- -->
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                 <?php }else{ ?>
                  <p><?php _e('Not a single Event is there','templatic');?></p>
                <?php } ?>
<?php

        echo '</ul>';

        echo $after_widget;
    }

    function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
    //save the widget
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
        $instance['category'] = strip_tags($new_instance['category']);
        $instance['post_number'] = strip_tags($new_instance['post_number']);
        $instance['post_link'] = strip_tags($new_instance['post_link']);
        $instance['more_link'] = strip_tags($new_instance['more_link']);
        $instance['character_cout'] = strip_tags($new_instance['character_cout']);
        $instance['event_sorting'] = strip_tags($new_instance['event_sorting']);
        return $instance;

    }

    function form($instance) {
    //widgetform in backend
        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array( 'title' => '', 'category' => '', 'post_number' => '','character_cout' => '','more_link' => '', 'event_sorting' => 'Latest Published' ) );
        $title = strip_tags($instance['title']);
        $category = strip_tags($instance['category']);
        $post_number = strip_tags($instance['post_number']);
        $post_link = strip_tags($instance['post_link']);
        $more_link = strip_tags($instance['more_link']);
        $character_cout = strip_tags($instance['character_cout']);
        $sorting = strip_tags($instance['event_sorting']);

?>
<p>
  <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php echo TITLE_TEXT; ?>:
    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>" />
  </label>
</p>
<p>
  <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('category'); ?>"><?php echo CATEGORY_IDS_TEXT; ?>:
  <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('category'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('category'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($category); ?>" />
  </label>  <p><?php echo fetch_categories_ids('eventcategory'); ?></p>
</p>
<p>
  <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('post_number'); ?>"><?php echo NUMBER_POSTS_TEXT; ?>:
  <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('post_number'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('post_number'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($post_number); ?>" />
  </label>
</p>
<p>
  <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('event_sorting'); ?>"><?php echo SORT_EVENT; ?>:
  <select name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('event_sorting'); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('event_sorting'); ?>">
    <option selected="selected" value="Latest Published"><?php _e('Latest Published','templatic'); ?></option>
    <option <?php if ($sorting == 'Random') { echo 'selected=selected'; } ?> value="Random"><?php _e('Random','templatic'); ?></option>
    <option <?php if ($sorting == 'Alphabetical') { echo 'selected=selected'; } ?> value="Alphabetical"><?php _e('Alphabetical','templatic'); ?></option>
    <option <?php if ($sorting == 's_date') { echo 'selected=selected'; } ?> value="s_date"><?php _e('As Per Start Date','templatic'); ?></option>
  </select>
  </label>
</p>
<?php
    }
}
register_widget('blaestfeatured');
// BLAEST FEATURED ENDS 
?>
```

I've tried a couple of nights for myself, but unfortunately my PHP skills are lackluster at best.

Edit: Updated with whole widget code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your query:

```
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'my_custom_post_type',
   'posts_per_page' => 10,
   'meta_query' => array(
       array(
           'key' => 'featured_h',
           'value' => 'h',
       )
   )
 );
 $query = new WP_Query($args);
 while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
     <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php get_post_class(); ?> ><?php } ?>
           <h3 class="<?php echo $postclasscategory; ?>" > <?php echo get_formated_date(get_post_meta($post->ID,'st_date',true));?> </h3>
           <div class="eventcontainer">
            <?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID,'featured_h',true) == 'h' ) { ?><div class="featured_img_s"></div><?php }?>
            <?php if ( $thumb != '' ) { ?>
            <a class="headliner-img" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" width="290" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"  /></a>
            <?php
            } else { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID) ; ?>" class="headliner-img"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()."/images/no-image.png"; ?>" height="120" alt="<?php echo @$post_img[0]['alt']; ?>" /></a>
            </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Good answer although `'meta_key'` isn't required when you're using a meta query.

Comment: Thank you so much! I know this is a rather retarded question again, but how do i use this to output it? I Tried to search some here, but it didnt make much sense :/

Comment: Thank you again! I cant get it to run though, probably because of the rest of my code I suspect.

Comment: see my new reply @Banago

Comment: Finally got it to not crash and to output something at all, but it still just prints the first five events :/

Comment: Yes, you have to add `'posts_per_page' => 10`, for example. Updated the code again.

Comment: Yes, but it doesnt print the next featured events, instead it prints any five events.. :/

Comment: Not that im using here now, since the whole code is based on another widget belonging to the theme im pretty sure it used to have it. Why ? @Banago